# bottomNavigation : ReselectedListener : Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, bottomnavigationview

I am using bottom navigation in my layout but when I try to write an on Click for it in my main activity oncreate it gives me an exception:

Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference
  private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: share your crash log and xml layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        }
    });
```